# How to add more row at the mail designer in mailchimp?

Tags: email, html-email, mailchimp, html-editor

I am using mailchimp mail template designer to create the template

first I select the basic template here:

[image]

the 3:1:3 column structure

And when I edit the template

[image]

I would like to create more row at the template e.g. 3 line of photos instead of 2 lines now, any mates have experience to add more row (and can select 1/2/3 column) at the mail template design?

thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: This isn't a question about programming. Maybe try the [web apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) board?

Comment: Still, this is a very good question. Did you manage to find out how to add more sections @user782104?